# PI speed control of DC motor using a boost chopper simulation in Simscape

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, dc-motor, simulink

My project is to regulate the speed of a DC motor (fed by a chopper boost) with a PI controller, after calculating the different parameters of the chopper which are as follows:

DC motor parameters:
5 HP, 240 V, 1750 RPM, field voltage = 300 V, Vin = 120 V, and Vo = 240 V.

Assuming f = 25 kHz, dI = 5%, and dV = 5%, the values of
the parameters are obtained as D = 0.5, L = 0.2724 mH, and C = 146.8 μF.

The diagram is as follows:

[image]

The problem that I have is that the output speed does not follow the given setpoint in any case.

I would like to ask some experts in the field if they can help me solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: This question is very broad and from the given information it is hard to say something useful. What do we see in the bottom diagram? Can you provide some setpoints and resulting speeds?

Comment: With this topology the armature voltage can never be lower than the input voltage (separate from diode drop and coil DCR). Is this intended?

Comment: for the lower diagram, the blue line represents the given set point (the speed of rotation that the motor should have at the output) while the yellow line represents the real speed of rotation of the output, we can notice that the motor is not regulated.

Comment: Otherwise the voltage drop is not wanted, I tried without command the chopper has overvoltage input but adding a command we had a drop I did not understand why

Comment: Welcome! Please use engineering notation instead of scientific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your units are wrong, you can find out if you do several steps to the control signal and if they linearly step with it then the control signal is off by constant. Usually in control systems you need to follow the units and make sure there is no constants and that the units cancel out correctly from the set point all the way through the control loop.